# What is the meaning of (\-?2|3) in regex

Tags: regex

In this regex I want to know the meaning for `\-?`

```
\b((m)(\-?2|3))
```

I get the following output:

```
Array
(
[0] => m2
[1] => m2
[2] => m
[3] => 2
)
```

Comment: This just makes hyphen optional before 2, also escaping is not needed so you can use: `\b((m)(-?2|3))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't say what the input string is.
`\-?` Means that there might be "-" symbol before the number. "?" is `"zero or one"`, `"-"` needs to be escaped by `"\"`, because it has special meaning in regex. So your regex will match `"m2"`, but also `"m-2"`.

Comment: `-` has no special meaning in regex, except when it's in certain positions in a character class, or part of a mode modifier shortcut, neither of which is the case here.

Comment: @TimPietzcker You're right. But still somebody escaped it just in case :).

Comment: slash is used for denoting ranges so it is used along with escape sequence.is it correct

Comment: @user3064914: No, it's superfluous at best, and incorrect at worst, because some regex engines treat unnecessary escapes as syntax errors.

Comment: I would have mentioned that the regexp will not match m-3.